# How to replace a special unicode character in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have some data in one of the Oracle table which contains this special unicode 
character (square with white question mark).  Here are the various representations

Unicode character           Oct     Dec     Hex     HTML
Results 1 - 1 of 1
�   replacement character

```
OCT = 0177775   
DEC = 65533 
HEX = 0xFFFD    
HTML = &#65533
```

I want to know how I can replace this symbol with say "^" while I'm selecting the data?  I know there's a REPLACE() function but I am not successful in using this.  Can someone help?

Thank you

Comment: What is the database character set? Also, use the `DUMP()` function on a string that contains the character, and find out what code value it has. (For example: `select dump('abc')` from dual returns `97,98,99` - the code for 'c' is 99.

Comment: [`0xFFFD`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0fffd/index.htm) is just the Unicode replacement character for something unknown or unrepresentable. Is that the actual value stored in the database, or is it just what your browser displays when it hits it?

Answer (score 2):

First convert the string to ASCII and then replace.

```
SELECT CONVERT('Ä Ê Í Õ Ø A B C D E ', 'UTF8', 'US7ASCII')
```

Look below documentation for different types char conversions.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm

Then use REPLACE.

Comment: This will work only if the specific character the OP is asking about exists in 'US7ASCII'. If it does not, it will not be converted correctly, and then the replacement may not work.